# Programmatically read a list of functions in a class, and pick one based on function name

Tags: python

I am trying to avoid to have a huge list of if-else code.

Basically I have a set of instructions that should run, based on the input. Imagine for sake of simplicity, a public office that release driver permits based on citizenship, health and so on.

The condition that I am using at the moment, is a string, so I use a function that accept a string as parameter; inside the function, I go through a sequence of if-else to find the appropriate function that run a sequence of commands. If new activities are added, I add a new function in the activity executor, with the instructions to run, and a new elif with the string used to run that function

```
def activity_manager(self, type_of_activity):

    if type_of_activity == "citizen":
        activity_executor.license_standard()
    elif type_of_activity == "senior":
        activity_executor.license_senior()
    elif [...]
       [ other cases, there are plenty]
    else:
        [ If there is no action associated print a message]


class activity_executor:

    def license_senior(self)
        [ Do stuff for the senior license]

    def license_standard(self)
        [ Do stuff for standard license]

    [ ... more functions that does something else]
```

Now, the problem with this approach, is that this can get out of hands easily.

Instead, I was hoping to do something different; something that would be dynamic, like doing introspection in the activity_executor class, reading the name of the functions; and executing the correct function based on the one that I want to run; like this:

```
activity_executor(license_standard)
```

If this function exist in that class, it will be executed; otherwise I get a message that say that there is no such function. In this way I can get rid of the activity_manager function, and just have a generic function that accept a function name as parameter; so if I add more functions in that class, I don't have to add if-elif conditions anywhere. Also this will eliminate the concern of handling cases where the function does not exist.

Is this feasible in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you have a one-on-one match between the parameter you get and the functions you want to execute, eg.

```
activity_executor('standard') # execute license_standard
activity_executor('senior')   # execute license_senior
```

Then you can call a method if you know its name with [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#getattr)():

```
class activity_executor:
    def activity_executor(self, activity):
      getattr(self, 'license_' + activity)()
```

That said, that way you couple very tightly parameters and method names, which might make future evolution a nightmare. I would suggest to use a dictionary instead, which lets you define all the business rules in one place only:

```
activities={
    'senior' => 'license_senior',
    'citizen' => 'license_citizen',
    # many more lines
}
```

which you can then use with getattr:

```
class activity_executor:
    def activity_executor(self, activity):
        method=activities[activity]
        getattr(self, method)()
```

You can first check for existence of the method with [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#hasattr)().

Works for pyhton 2 & 3.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `getattr`, for example:

```
try:
    function = getattr(activity_executor, 'license_' + type_of_activity)
    assert callable(function)  # make sure it is a function
                               # or a callable in general
except AttributeError:
    pass # function not found print a message
else:
    # found function call it
    function()
```